# React Testing Library Error: Uncaught [TypeError: _scrollViewRef$curren.scrollTo is not a function]

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a react component

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './PopularBrands.scss';
import LG from '../../../assets/images/brands/LG.png';
import Google from '../../../assets/images/brands/Google.jpeg';
import Apple from '../../../assets/images/brands/Apple.png';
import Boch from '../../../assets/images/brands/Boch.png';
import Dyson from '../../../assets/images/brands/Dyson.png';
import Philips from '../../../assets/images/brands/Philips.png';
import Samsung from '../../../assets/images/brands/Samsung.png';
import Simens from '../../../assets/images/brands/Simens.png';
import Sony from '../../../assets/images/brands/Sony.png';
import Xiomi from '../../../assets/images/brands/Xiomi.png';
import { FaChevronLeft } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { FaChevronRight } from 'react-icons/fa';

const PopularBrands = () => {
  const scrollViewRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const [screenWidth, setScreenWidth] = useState(0);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const [widthTotal, setWidthTotal] = useState(0);
  const [showArrow, setShowArrow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleWindowResize() {
      if (scrollViewRef.current) setWidth(scrollViewRef.current.clientWidth);
      if (scrollViewRef.current) setWidthTotal(scrollViewRef.current.scrollWidth);
    }

    handleWindowResize();

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollViewRef.current?.scrollTo({ left: screenWidth, behavior: 'smooth' });
  }, [screenWidth]);

  const toNextPage = () => {
    if (scrollViewRef && screenWidth <= widthTotal) {
      setScreenWidth(screenWidth + width);
    }
  };

  const toPreviosPage = () => {
    if (scrollViewRef && screenWidth >= 0) {
      setScreenWidth(screenWidth - width);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="brandsContainer"
      onMouseEnter={() => setShowArrow(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setShowArrow(false)}>
      <div className="brands" ref={scrollViewRef}>
        <div>
          <img src={LG} alt="lg" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src={Google} alt="Google" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src={Apple} alt="Apple" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src={Boch} alt="Boch" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src={Dyson} alt="Dyson" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src={Philips} alt="Philips" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src={Samsung} alt="Samsung" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src={Simens} alt="Simens" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src={Sony} alt="Sony" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src={Xiomi} alt="Xiomi" />
        </div>
      </div>
      {screenWidth > 0 && showArrow && (
        <div className="scrollIcon scrollBack" onClick={toPreviosPage}>
          <FaChevronLeft fontSize={30} />
        </div>
      )}

      {screenWidth + width < widthTotal && showArrow && (
        <div className="scrollIcon scrollNext" onClick={toNextPage}>
          <FaChevronRight fontSize={30} />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PopularBrands;
```

It works properly in th UI. But when I write the following unit test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import PopularBrands from './PopularBrands';

describe('PopularBrands', () => {
  test.only('renders the component', () => {
    render(<PopularBrands />);

    expect(screen.getByAltText('lg')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByAltText('Google')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByAltText('Apple')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByAltText('Boch')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByAltText('Dyson')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByAltText('Philips')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByAltText('Samsung')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByAltText('Simens')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByAltText('Sony')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByAltText('Xiomi')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

The test is not passing and i get the error log:

```
  ● PopularBrands › renders the component

    TypeError: _scrollViewRef$curren.scrollTo is not a function

      37 |
      38 |   useEffect(() => {
    > 39 |     scrollViewRef.current?.scrollTo({ left: screenWidth, behavior: 'smooth' });
         |                            ^
      40 |   }, [screenWidth]);
      41 |
      42 |   const toNextPage = () => {

      at src/components/Directory/PopularBrands/PopularBrands.tsx:39:28
```

I'm trying to get help for fixing my Unit tests. On the useEffect functions there is a depedency screenWidth and when that change we scroll to the begining of the Icons list.

Comment: The UI for the component https://shopping-87340.web.app/.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue. I was able to make the test pass and get rid of the error by adding this:

```
Element.prototype.scrollTo = jest.fn();
```

By adding it to your setupTests file setupTests file it should get rid of the error, but since it's now a mock you won't be able to test the functionality ether.

Furthermore, I've fond that the testing-library is not prepared or equiped to test scroll events, if you want to test them, you need a browser-based testing enviroment and not a node besed one like jest and testing-library.

Hope this helps.

**Edit1:**

You can test however only that the function has been called with something like:

```
expect(Element.prototype.scrollTo).toHaveBeenCalled();
```